# Rebol2 can not connect to MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, rebol, rebol2

I just tried to use Rebol2 with MariaDB using the mysql-driver from softinnov

```
>> read mysql://user:password@localhost/mysql/test
** User Error: ERROR 1251 : Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MariaDB client
** Near: read mysql://localhost/mysql/test
```

Is there a newer version than 1.2.1 available or do I have to use a dynamic loadable library?

Comment: What version of the MySQL is MariaDB based on?

Comment: I'd ask Nenad directly on gitter

Comment: I got an answer on Altme. When writing that here, I got many downvotes, so I decided to delete the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using the -41 version as at the following location will fix this.

From https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/291/2013/11/10/0-23,

@rgchris Thanks very much for the link, didn't know that Nenad / @DocKimbel created an alternative version of MySQL protocol :

http://softinnov.org/tmp/mysql-protocol-41.r